# How to stub nested models to test a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a relation: `Transaction belongs_to Post` (has_many)

And I have this view:

```
# /app/views/transactions/index.html.haml

%h3 Transactions
%table
  %tr 
    %th Item
    %th Description
    %th Money
  - @transactions.each do |transaction|
    %tr 
      %td= transaction.description
      %td= number_to_currency(transaction.money)
      %td= link_to transaction.post.title, transaction.post.link # (!)
```

If I didn't have the last line - I would test it like so:

```
before(:each) do
  assign(:transactions, [
    stub_model(Transaction,
      { description: "Posted", money: 9.99 }
    ),
    stub_model(Transaction,
      { description: "Posted", money: 9.99 }
    )
  ])
end

it "renders a list of transactions" do
  render
  assert_select "tr>th", :text => "Description"
  assert_select "tr>th", :text => "Money"
  assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Posted", :count => 2
  assert_select "tr>td", :text => number_to_currency(9.99).to_s, :count => 2
end
```

But I don't know how to test the last line of the view, which displays information of the post it belongs to.

I've read about `stub_chain`, but can't figure out how to fit it there to stub entier model.
Tried to stub Post first, and then assign post_id for stubbed Transaction - didn't work either..

Or should I test it on Capybara level?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way.

Just did:

```
before(:each) do
  assign(:transactions, [
    stub_model(Transaction,
      { description: "Posted", money: 9.99, post: mock_model(Post, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:post)) }
    ),
    stub_model(Transaction,
      { description: "Posted", money: 9.99, post: mock_model(Post, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:post)) }
    )
  ])
end
```